# How to show specific HTML content when selecting certain date in jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm sorry if this is an obvious thing (or if this question has been asked before), but I searched before writing this, and maybe my answer was somewhere, but since I'm new to this, I'm sorry if I missed it.

So I am trying to use Jquery UI's datepicker to set up a calendar as an archive. And I want when someone clicks on a date from the calendar, to show the event from that day(with details and all).

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Icon trigger</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/js/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="vendors/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"> test</p>

</body>
</html>
```

On the same subject, how can I mark in the calendar the dates that actually have an event, so people don't browse without aim, searching for the days that actually have events?

Comment: where are the events? in some database?

Comment: @yuri-tkachenko I would prefer if I can just add them in the html code and it should stay hidden until the date is selected. For example:    

<code> <div class="event" id="event-2016-04-13"> Title details etc. </div> </code>
But if that's not possible, any suggesting would be good.

Comment: take a look at: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just very fast answer to your question you can define function `onSelect` in date picker (http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) and use it to control what to show.

I did very simple demo.

HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />Test</p>

<div id="log">
   <div class="event" id="event-2016-04-13"> Title details etc. 13 </div>
   <div class="event" id="event-2016-04-12"> Title details etc. 12 </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.event {
  display: none;
}
```

JS (modified):

```
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    //added
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(dateText, datepicker) {
      // hide all events
      $('#log').find('.event').hide(); 
      // show only one that selected
      var event = '#event-' + dateText;
      $(event).show();
    }
  });
});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/m0y3fc9x/4](https://jsfiddle.net/m0y3fc9x/4/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! One more question. How Can I make the previous event hide again when I select another date?

Comment: @elyiz updated answer. `$('#log').find('.event').hide();` this line does the trick! ;)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again! And I actually understand what is happening in the JS, with the help of your commentaries in there!